# Where shall I look for a job?

Tags: job

hello everyone,

I have been on the hunt for various sound job vacancies. But I am having trouble finding advertisements in this field. Im looking to find paid work as I have some experience in working with aspiring film makers but cannot find anything available. Please help. I know that finding a pay job is by looking at the right place at the right time but is there websites that you guys use that I haven't used before? I use mandy broadcasting, film crew pro and talent circle.

Hope all is well guys

Answer (score 5):

Its going to be really tough to find a job through just a posting online. While I'm not saying it can't happen, the easiest way to find a job, whether it be a full time gig or just for a shoot is going to happen through word of mouth. One of the biggest things that I've learned in the past two years of graduating with an audio degree is that the network of friends and acquaintances that I've made have gotten me all of the work. Another good thing for you to do is intern somewhere. A friend of mine interned at a few different places and he ended up getting a job at Sony in their video game department doing sound design.

The best thing that you can do is just act as professional as you can on every gig you get, be it a commercial, a feature film or even a short film. Make yourself as marketable as you can, by having good equipment or showcasing skills that are unique to you, so that people will seek you out. Chances are that one of the very people you might be crewed up with can get you a better job than the one you have now.

Good Luck and Godspeed!

Answer (score 1):

Like Ruben says in this business networking is everything. I would suggest you to put all your efforts in meeting people all the time and leave always a good and professional impression.

A tip I use is trying to get along with the non-sound crew, specially. This is because they are not a "rival" for you and in a future gig hopefully they could remember you. For me, this works specially with DoP's.

Another advice I can give is to have a nice online presence. Once someone know you, you'll want to have a good and clear website showing what you do and every possible way to connect with you.

And my last advice would be to have patience. The seeds will grow.

Answer (score 0):

Also always stay positive about your skills and have a great attitude so do not let anything nor anyone disappoint you. Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

I agree COMPLETELY. I was JUST telling a friend the same thing yesterday. My biggest realization was that word of mouth was the best form of advertisement. About a year and a half ago my partner and I did a short for very little money and on a tight schedule - but we stayed positive, presented ourselves professionally and our work was impressive and we've been working steadily ever since. Our next film project is always booked before our current was is over. Each a little more professional and better paying.

BEST OF LUCK TO YOU. TO US ALL REALLY.